# How to fix the codes with the newest pydrake bindings?

Tags: drake

I found a useful demo in github(https://github.com/maggiewu19/compass-gait-simulator). However, the codes didn't work with the newest pydrake. I ran the codes in google colab  and got errors.

Any reply will be appreciated.

Comment: It will be much easier for us to help if you were to link to your colab notebook and show the specific errors that you are getting.

Comment: My colab notebook [link] (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vH3ElDGiQK4HMXR56bTyhC6tDe6gIYN_?usp=sharing). I got a lot of errors, such as 'ImportError: cannot import name 'FloatingBaseType'
I know it means the pydrake has updated and it is not suitable to use the code written last year. However, I am not familiar with pydrake api. Maybe I will find a solution sooner. It is still not easy for me to figure it out now.

Answer (score 0):

I see.  This is quite old -- it is using `RigidBodyPlant` which has been replaced by `MultibodyPlant`.

Drake has supported quite a long deprecation period on this.  You can make most of it work by pulling the old `RigidBodyPlant` classes from `attic`, e.g. by changing this

```
from pydrake.all import (Box,
                         DiagramBuilder,
                         FindResourceOrThrow,
                         Isometry3,
                         SignalLogger,
                         Simulator)
from pydrake.attic.all import (FloatingBaseType, RigidBodyTree, RigidBodyPlant, VisualElement)
```

Unfortunately, I didn't leave as long of a deprecation period on `PlanarRigidBodyVisualizer` in the underactuated repo.  You will have to pull an old version of `underactuated` to make that work.

FTR -- we are currently working on a way to make the colab setup's durable, by having a peg revision of drake (and underactuated) in the setup script.  For now, you could download the old version of the underactuated repo, or just that [specific file that was removed after it's deprecation period.](https://github.com/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/ebd0f1fe1a3d867b53835307537503d9ef5ea8d0/underactuated/deprecated/planar_rigid_body_visualizer.py)

I can't guarantee you won't hit more errors after that.  It would be much better to use the [updated compass gait examples](http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/simple_legs.html) from class which are all using `MultibodyPlant`.

Comment: In the updated compass gait examples, I am confused how could I move the camera view along the x axe to avoid the disappearance of the robot when the robot keeping walking.

Comment: And I don't know how to get  the right leg information in the simulation, as floating_base_state
returns  reference to the output port that provides the state in the floating-base coordinates (described via left leg xyz & rpy + hip angle + derivatives)